# Why isn't my Javascript animating this text for color change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Not sure why this isn't resulting in color change animation on the successful result. I was just playing around with some animation for the first time and I can't figure out why this won't work. Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<p>Roll two dice and see if they align:</p>
<p id="answerSpace"></p>
```

CSS

```
    #answerSpace {
  font-size: 52px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

p{
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0% { color: red; }
  50% { color: blue; }
  100% { color: red; }
}
```

Javascript

```
const randomNum = num => {

let answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(num))

return answer;

};

const compareRolls = () => {

let firstRoll = randomNum(6); console.log("first roll: " + firstRoll);
let secondRoll = randomNum(6); console.log("second roll: " + secondRoll);

if (firstRoll === secondRoll){
a = true; result = "You did it!" + ` Two ${firstRoll}s!`}else{  a=false; result ="nope."}

console.log(a);

let space = document.getElementById("answerSpace");
if (a == true){space.style.animation = "color-change 1s infinite;"}

space.innerHTML = result;

};

compareRolls();
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the Javascript and just set the html to the state that it would be in when it should animate?  That's step one in scoping down where the problem is.

Comment: Yes it does, sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: In that case, please make a [mcve] with your logic.  We need more context into the issue, specifically when the logic executes in relation to the markup.

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox example? the js code you provided isn't valid.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2tmvrsa/10/

Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had a semi-colon in your CSS which was causing an error.

```js
const randomNum = num => {

let answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(num))

return answer;

};

const compareRolls = () => {

let firstRoll = randomNum(6); console.log("first roll: " + firstRoll);
let secondRoll = randomNum(6); console.log("second roll: " + secondRoll);

if (firstRoll === secondRoll){
a = true; result = "You did it!" + ` Two ${firstRoll}s!`}else{  a=false; result ="nope."}

console.log(a);

let space = document.getElementById("answerSpace");
if (a == true){
space.style.animation = "1s ease 0s infinite normal none running color-change";
}

space.innerHTML = result;

};

compareRolls();
```

```css
#answerSpace {
  font-size: 52px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

p{
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0% { color: red; }
  50% { color: blue; }
  100% { color: red; }
}
```

```html
<p>Roll two dice and see if they align:</p>
<p id="answerSpace"></p>
```

Comment: i think yes the semicolon in space.style.animation was causing problem

Comment: Thank you! I feel slightly dumb, but I suppose it happens.

Comment: @Richard can you mark my post as the answer and upvote

Comment: @lifeiscontent oh, sorry about that. I'm kind of new here. I just did! Thanks again!